# View's Background Color Removed When Using RelativeLayout In ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, colors, android-relativelayout

While working with ListViews I ran into an interesting issue. So my goal was to write an xml layout for a custom ListView item design.

First of all, here is the problematic xml layout (problem described below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notebook_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notebook_color_tag"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/notebook_color_tag"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout is fairly basic, just a `View`, that's used to **display a color**, and a `TextView`.

I have a subclass of `ListFragment` which uses an instance of a subclass of `CursorAdapter` in its `setListAdapter()` method. In that custom `CursorAdpater`'s `bindView()` I set the `View`'s color and the `TextView`'s text (that code is not the problem, you can ignore it, it's just here for referrence):

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView notebookName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notebook_title);
    View colorTag = view.findViewById(R.id.notebook_color_tag);

    String name = cursor.getString(NOTEBOOK_NAME_POS);
    int color = cursor.getInt(NOTEBOOK_COLOR_POS);

    notebookName.setText(name);
    colorTag.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Now, the problem is that if the `View`'s `android:layout_height` is set to `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, the `View` simply does not appear in the `ListView`'s items. It seems as it has some margin at the top. If a concrete width value is specified, for example:           `android:layout_height="40dp"`, everything works fine.

Here is how the bogus layout looks:

[image: Erroneous ListView]

Here is how it should look:

[image: Correct ListView]

As explained above, the blue rectangle does not seem to be inside the `ListView`'s item container at all (but the element is there, it's accessible via `findViewById()` and it's color **does get changed** via the `setBackgroundColor()`call, the `View` simply seems not to be displayed).

The follwoing change to the layout fixes the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/notebook_color_tag"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notebook_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I understand that `LinearLayout` makes more sense here than the `RelativeLayout`, but I'm curious what was wrong in the `RelativeLayout`'s case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate 'notebook_color_tag' ID's. You are adding it twice in the first layout XML (as a parameter in the `TextView` and also as a child of the layout).

Also, I would reverse the order, like so:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/notebook_color_tag"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notebook_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notebook_color_tag"
    />
```

Since the `RelativeLayout` will create and place in the order of the XML, this is more efficient (it does not have to remeasure to place the views correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea how that passed unnoticed. This is really awkward.